# windows iot raspberry pi virtual serial

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-iot-core-10

I created an UWP application for my Raspberry Pi 2 model b+ with Windows iot core.
This application controls my lights, thermostat and ventsystem.
To control my ventsystem i have a Moxa NPort 5230 connected to it. 
This device is a LAN server creating a serialport over LAN. For Windows 10 there is a driver that allows me to create a virtual serial port (as in COM1 -> redirects to ie 192.168.0.1) connecting to that device.
I contacted Moxa to ask if there is a driver for Windows iot core, but there isn't unfortunatly.

To solve my problem, i am looking for a way to install a virtual serial port on my Windows iot core that redirects to the local ipaddress of the Moxa device.
Does someone have experience with this?

If this is **not** possible in Windows iot...
Is there a way to send data in c# to this device with specific bautrate etc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows IoT Core does not support virtual serial port.Raspberry Pi 2 Model B+ has on-board serial port and 4 USB ports.You can connect NPort 5230 to Pi2 directly with on-board serial port(by referring to PIN mapping in the specification of Raspberry Pi 2 Model B+).Another way is that,you can connect it with USB to TTL Serial Converter Module,currently only CP2102 USB 2.0 to TTL Module Serial Converter is supported officially,you can refer to this [hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/HardwareCompatList) for more information.In addition,you can follow the offical sample of [Serial UART Communication](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/SerialUART).